# Privilege escalation in Linux 2.6.32

Tags: linux, privilege-escalation

I am in an audit and I need to show the client that privileges can be scaled but I have tried in various ways and I could not. The Kernel version is 2.6.32-754.3.5.el6.x86_64.

I have already tried using DirtyCOW, but the problem is that I always get "sh: denied permissions". And in fact, gcc also has root only permissions.

I'm a user without privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll go out on a limb and guess that any directory your user has permission to write to is mounted as noexec, which means that you will not be able to directly execute anything. To run a shell script despite this, you can always do `bash script.sh` if doing `./script.sh` fails with a permission denied error. You should try looking for any directory you can write to which you can also execute from. If none exist, then even having gcc would not help you, since you could not execute the code it generates.

In order to exploit DirtyCow, you need to invoke a number of system calls. This cannot be done from within a shell script. You either need to use a sufficiently sophisticated scripting language such as Python and re-write the exploit in it, or you need to compromise a binary that you have the rights to run and make it run shellcode to perform the attack. If you aren't able to do that, I suggest you practice binary exploitation and shellcode development first to learn how, or this will be quite hard.

Comment: I was reviewing the files that are with SUID, but nothing I can do. There is a "mount" that has SUID but the problem is that I could not mount something with / bin / bash because not even in "/ tmp" I have privileges. Does it affect something that is a shared hosting? Could I do symlink?

Comment: @pignitulto What is your current goal, to execute machine code?

Comment: I was thinking about showing the client the escalation of privileges, but I am seeing that it is complicated. Is it possible that when doing Symlink, take the other web pages?.

Edit: One of my goals was to be able to show him that in / home he could access his websites. But since I do not have root

Comment: @pignitulto I don't know your target well enough to say anything about that. Yes, it is complicated, but it is certainly possible to exploit the system. You will need to gain code execution (either by finding a directory you can execute binaries on) or by getting shellcode to run on some vulnerable program (not necessarily suid). From there, you can run e.g. DirtyCow. Just find a vulnerable program...

Comment: When you mentioned to me to do the Dirtyc0w exploit in python, is that possible? since in the end, from python I would have to make system calls and go back to the same point

Comment: It would probably be possible if you can make syscalls directly. Do you know how DirtyCow works? If so, you should be able to do it.

Comment: I was reading the DirtyC0w code and apparently, it can be done in Python. What important call to the system could you try to verify that when you do this it works?

Comment: @pignitulto You should learn how DirtyCow works. You map a read-only file into memory and, if the exploit works, you are able to overwrite some of it. Consider using cron scripts as targets instead of the more obvious `/etc/passwd`, because the latter, if corrupted by the exploit, can break the system.

Comment: When you mean to use "cron scripts", what do you mean? I have the concept and I have handled cron, but I do not want to break the system and the client gets upset

Comment: Oh, I got it, when I'm going to run dirtyc0w, right? (target_file and new_content)

Comment: @pignitulto Any exploit has the potential of breaking the system. If you are doing penetration testing, they should write up a contract that tells you exactly what you can and cannot do. And by using cron scripts, I mean writing to them with DirtyCow to do something you want as root. For example, append the line `chmod +s /bin/sed` to a cronjob to get a backdoor in the form of a setuid `sed`.

Comment: In the contractual matter is, what worries me is that then something goes wrong (although it is in the contract). On the other hand, I will take your advice to do it with files that do not alter / etc / passwd and simply when I show you, I will try to show you that it is possible. Thank you very much for your time Forest, you are very kind!

Comment: Btw it's COW, not c0w. It stands for Copy-on-Write.